# Error using property map in boost graph library

Tags: boost-graph

i have the following code

```
typedef property<symbol_t,string,property <message_t,string> > edge_properties;
typedef property<vertex_name_t,string> vertex_properties;
typedef adjacency_list<listS,listS,directedS,vertex_properties,edge_properties> Graph;

Graph automata;
property_map(Graph,vertex_name_t) :: type state_name_map = get(vertex_name_t,automata);
```

this should work but i am getting the following errors

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘property_map’ with no type [-fpermissive]
xml2automata.cpp:30:37: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
xml2automata.cpp:30:39: error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::type’ without an 
argument list
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
property_map(Graph,vertex_name_t) :: type state_name_map = 
      get(vertex_name_t,automata);
```

channge the round brackets to angle brackets, since this is a template.

```
property_map < Graph,vertex_name_t > :: type state_name_map = 
       get(vertex_name_t,automata);
```